# How to slow down program execution

Tags: executable, strcmp, benchmarking, client-side-attacks

I have a simple executable binary. It takes as input a user supplied string and compares it with a private string using `strcmp`. How can I slow down the execution of this program such that I can launch a statistical timing attack on the string comparison? Currently the early-exit nature of `strcmp` is too slight to detect.

Assume I have local privileges, the binary is owned by another user, and the system is `ulimit` protected against fork bombs.

While I get that I could use the strings command or reverse engineering to get the private string, this is intended as a POC for the feasibility of timing attacks on compiled programs on modern systems.